# unable to start cqlsh for cassandra 3.7.0 : giving syntax error

Tags: python, cassandra

I have installed Cassandra 3.7.0 and have set path for pyhton as well. 
When I try to start cqlsh from the command line with below command,

python cqlsh localhost 9160

I am getting error as,

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
File "cqlsh". line 20 python -c 'import sys; sys.exit(not (0x020700b0 < sys.hexversion < 0x03000000))' 2>/dev/null \

can anyone help to resolve this.

Thanks,

Comment: What you're trying to do is to start a shell script with the python interpreter. Try running `./cqlsh` in the `CASSANDRA_HOME/bin` directory directly from command line.

Comment: -Stefan, thank you so much for looking into this. As you suggested, from the command line I just browsed into CASSANDRA_HOME\bin directory and entered the command ./cqlsh. But I got error as " .(dot) is not recognized as a command". Am I making any mistake here? Please correct me.

Comment: What Linux version are you using? Where does `/bin/sh` point to you your system (ls -l /bin/sh)?